# Changing a single jQuery plugin option on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I'm looking to change a single jQuery plugin option when the window hits certain breakpoints.

The code below works, however I'm conscious of repeating code and feel there is a more elegant way writing code for examples like this.

My initial thoughts would be to store the first call in a variable.

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {

        if ( config.wWidth >= 768 && config.wWidth <= 1024 ) {

            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                accordionW       : config.wWidth,
                accordionH       : config.wHeight,
                visibleSlices    : 2,
                expandedHeight   : 600,
                expandedWidth    : 1000,
                contentAnimSpeed : 200
            });

        } else if ( config.wWidth < 768 ) {

            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                accordionW       : config.wWidth,
                accordionH       : config.wHeight,
                visibleSlices    : 1,
                expandedHeight   : 600,
                expandedWidth    : 1000,
                contentAnimSpeed : 200
            });

        } else {

            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                accordionW       : config.wWidth,
                accordionH       : config.wHeight,
                visibleSlices    : 3,
                expandedHeight   : 600,
                expandedWidth    : 1000,
                contentAnimSpeed : 200
            });
        }

    });

    $(window).trigger("smartresize");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {

  var chosenSettings;

  // We could map out the defaults first.
  var defaults = {
    accordionW: config.wWidth,
    accordionH: config.wHeight,
    visibleSlices: 0,
    expandedHeight: 600,
    expandedWidth: 1000,
    contentAnimSpeed: 200
  };

  // Then, depending on the conditions, create an object of the modifications
  // This way, it's easier to add in more differences.
  if (config.wWidth >= 768 && config.wWidth <= 1024) {
    chosenSettings = {visibleSlices: 2};
  } else if (config.wWidth < 768) {
    chosenSettings = {visibleSlices: 1};
  } else {
    chosenSettings = {visibleSlices: 3};
  }

  // Then use extend to create an object with the chosen settings
  var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, chosenSettings);
  $('#va-accordion').vaccordion(settings);  

// Assuming smartresize returns the same object, we can chain trigger.
}).trigger('smartresize');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after... it will be a great help for my future work as well, thank you

Comment: That's a great solution Joseph! Let me suggest moving the if block to a method that receives config and returns the chosenSettings. I think that will be even better! :)

Comment: @Juliano I didn't do that because I assumed this function gets called on resize, and a function inside this would be bad for performance as it is created everytime it is called.

Comment: I didn't think about it, excellent point!

Answer (score 3):

You might extract your code to a function to remove the repeated code, passing the values ​​that change as parameters:

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {

    if (config.wWidth >= 768 && config.wWidth <= 1024) {
        createVaccordion(config, 2);

    } else if (config.wWidth < 768) {
        createVaccordion(config, 1);

    } else {
        createVaccordion(config, 3);
    }

    function createVaccordion(config, slices) {
        $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
            accordionW: config.wWidth,
            accordionH: config.wHeight,
            visibleSlices: slices,
            expandedHeight: 600,
            expandedWidth: 1000,
            contentAnimSpeed: 200
        });
    }
});

$(window).trigger("smartresize");
```

Comment: This is a method I hadn't considered, thank you. I've gone with an alternative solution, but marked this up.